# Life expectancy by cohort demography package R

Tags: r

I need to calculate life expectancy for several cohorts. I have used `demography` package, it seems to be prepared for receiving data by period (example: death rate in 2001, 2002, 2003...).

I need to calculate life expectancy by cohort and I have data available only by cohort (example: death rate of people born in 2001, 2002, and so on).

Comment: it seems like you should be able to use the same function but just alter your interpretation of the results based on the data you input into it. Nevertheless, have you considered survival analysis? https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Survival.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, package 'survival' doesn't meet my needs because it's intended to calculate survival probability in a certain time for each individual, however I need to calculate the whole life expectancy for a cohort.